# Regular expression que verifique a presença dum pattern que se repete

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Como faço uma expressão regular dizendo que essa tem que se repetir exatamente um tot de vezes? Por exemplo, gostaria de verificar se uma linha dum file contem este pattern `|1_CHAR` exatamente por 8 vezes. Já agora, é possível por exemplo dizer que o tipo de caracter tem que ser ou `espaço`, ou `o`, ou `*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `{n}` para algo que repete um número fixo de vezes. Por exemplo, a expressão regular `a{8}` reconhece uma sequência de 8 caracteres `a`.

Além disso, também tem `{n,m}` para "de n a m repetições' e `{,m}` e `{n,}` para "até m repetições e "pelo menos n repetições", respectivamente.

Comment: `\w` reconhece um caractere alfanumérico - acho que sua regex fica certa se você tirar os `\w`s (e talvez adicionar um `\|` no final para reconhecer a 9a barra vertical)

Comment: É assim mesmo. Se não der match o `re.match` retorna `None` ao invés de um Match Object portanto basta converter `i` pra booleano ou passar ele prum `if`